# ARN structure in Cloud formation template for AWS GovClouds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an offering on AWS for different regions. But for GovCloud regions ARN structure is different from normal ones. As we use ARN, normal deployment is failing in Gov regions.
For this I have added a check whether region name is Gov region or not. But I had to hardcode the regions name.
Is there any generalize conditions to check present region is a Gov region in CFT?

Comment: I'm working right now with some templates created by AWS, they do a check in there and the region is hard coded: `"GovCloudCondition":{
            "Fn::Equals":[
                {
                    "Ref":"AWS::Region"
                },
                "us-gov-west-1"
            ]
        }`

Comment: This is what we have done. but looking for some other better solution by not to comparing to any hardcoded region

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When deploying into another AWS partition (Gov Cloud or China), I would recommend using the pseduo parameter ${AWS::Partition}, for example

`arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1:123456789012:environment/My App/MyEnvironment`

would look like

`!Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:elasticbeanstalk:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:environment/My App/MyEnvironment`

Those pseduo params will be substituted based on the partition/region/account you are in.

Further reading on pseudo parameters here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly I was looking for.